# nested NavigationController causing uiview resize

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have nested a navigation controller inside another and now its causing the uiview inside the nested navigationcontroller to resized weirdly.

Here are a few screen shots to show you whats going on.

This is with both navigation bars showing, as you can see the bottom extends further than the physical screen can allow.
[image]

this one only shows the sub navbar with the main nav bar hidden.. as you can see there is this weird space above the subbar that looks like the height of a status bar. i'm not sure what it is.
[image]

Lastly this shows only the mainnavbar being shown and the subbar being hidden..
[image]

the last view is what I would like to use, However.. if you look at the bottom of the view its only got a portion of the A's displaying.. however if you look to the view in InterfaceBuilder on the left you will see that interface there should be more letters there but strangely the view is not resizing to fit in the bound of the physical view...

I am wondering hopefully with the detail supplied if you can tell me how to get the view to resize correctly and fit everything in properly.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set the autoresizeMask property = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin for these UILabel objects, you'll get the last UILabel aligned to the bottom of your UIView.

Comment: I selected the bottom red line in Interface builder just now for autoresizing.. and this didnt help.. do you think thats the same thing as you have mentioned in your answer?

Comment: The DetailViewController view is under the SubNavController or the MainNavController?

Comment: Under the SubNavController.. This is how I have added the detail view to the subNav **DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [otherNav pushViewController:detailView animated:NO];**

Comment: You'll need to set the autoresizingMask property of this detailView = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight.

Comment: @BernadoAssis dose this look right **[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ];
** if so it didnt work :(

Comment: actually! it worked! :)
like this

[otherNav.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

Comment: Great! A tip: Always set the autoresizeMask property of the subview in the view who you are adding this subview. I hope this helps! Thanks!